# Как вынести свою директиву в другой файл на Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Как вынести свою директиву в другой файл на Vue 3?

```js
app.directive('scroll-list', (el, binding) => {
        console.log(binding.value.color);
    })
```

Comment: Вы хотите вынести код директивы в отдельный файл?

Comment: @Mikalai Parakhnevich Да.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пользовательская директива определяется как **объект**, содержащий обработчики жизненного цикла, аналогичные обработчикам компонента.

Вынесите логику вашей директивы в отдельный файл (оформите ее в виде именованного экспорта объекта):

```
// scrollList.js
export const scrollList = {
  mounted(el, binding, vnode, prevVnode) {
    console.log(binding.value.color);
  },
}
```

Затем можете импортировать эту директиву (объект) в нужный компонент, как:

```
import { scrollList } from './scrollList'

export default {
  setup() {
    /*...*/
  },
  directives: {
    // включает v-scroll-list в шаблоне
    scrollList,
  }
}
```

или зарегистрировать ее глобально:

```
import { scrollList } from './scrollList'
const app = createApp({})

// сделать v-scroll-list пригодным для использования во всех компонентах
app.directive('scrolList', scrollList)
```

```js
// этот объект, который описывает функционал пользовательской директивы можно вынести
//  в отдельный файл и импортировать в нужное место в приложении
const scrollList = {
  mounted(el, binding, vnode, prevVnode) {
    console.log(binding.value.color);
  },
}

const app = Vue.createApp({
  // использование директивы только в текущем компоненте
  directives: {
    // включает v-scroll-list в шаблоне компонента
    scrollList,
  }
})

// глобальная регистрация директивы
// app.directive('scrollList', scrollList)

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="main" v-scroll-list="{ color: 'red' }"></div>
</div>
```